# React: How to display error on incorrect user login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-dom

I am a beginner in React and was implementing a function where on a button click in the render method, I go to a function foo. In that function, I am sending the username and password to a server.

If the username and password are correct, it returns a JSON object like

```
{"Result":1,"Cookie":"COOKIE!!!"}
```

Now, if the Result is 0, I want to print an error message saying invalid username and password and if it correct, I want to redirect it to a different component class. Can someone please help me?

I have tried reading a lot of posts but cannot do it. The issue is, I want to print something on the webpage but that can only be done in render. I am in a function foo when I get the cookie so I do not know how to print an error message.

I also do not know how to take it to a new page on successful authentication, ie, the cookie will be 1

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';
import LoginImage from './LoginImage.png'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
//import Logfailed from './Logfailed'
import Flood from './Flood'

class UserLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {userName:'', password:'', act:'l', flag:0};
    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

   async handleClick(e) {
    const url = 'http://52.8.557.164/user'
    const data = {username:this.state.userName, password:this.state.password, action:this.state.act};
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        });
        const json = await response.json();
      if(json['Result'] === 1) {
        this.state.flag=1; 
      }
      else {
        this.state.flag=2;
      }
        console.log('Success', JSON.stringify(json));
      console.log(json['Cookie']);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error', error);
    }

 }

 handleChange1(e) {
  this.setState({userName: e.target.value})
 }
 handleChange2(e) {
  this.setState({password: e.target.value})
 }


render() {
  const err = this.state.flag;
    return (
        <div className = 'outer-container' ref={this.props.containerRef}> 
            <div className = 'header'> Login </div>
            <div className="content">
      <div className="image">
              <img src={LoginImage} />
      </div>

            <Form className = 'form'>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" className = 'form-group'>
          <Form.Label style={{marginTop: '90px'}}>Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Text className="text-muted" htmlFor="username"></Form.Text>
          <input type="text" value = {this.state.userName} name="username" placeholder="username" onChange={this.handleChange1}/>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword" className = 'form-group'>
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Text className="text-muted" htmlFor="password"></Form.Text>
          <input type="password" value = {this.state.password}  name="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.handleChange2} />
        </Form.Group>
        </Form>
            </div>
            <div className="footer">
                <Button variant="outline-primary" size="lg" onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn" block>
                    Login
                </Button>
            </div>
         </div>
    );
}   
}

export default UserLogin;
```

Comment: you can just define an empty errorMessage in your state and render it, then you can give it a text value in the function that handles the authentication. concerning the redirection i recommand you to use react router

Answer (score 3):

First off, in your handleClick() method, you are trying to directly modify your component's state instead of using React's built-in setState() method. This will prevent your UI from reacting to the update as React will have no way of knowing the state of your component has changed.

```
if(json['Result'] === 1) {
    this.state.flag=1; 
} else {
    this.state.flag=2;
}
```

Instead, if you replace that code with:

```
if(json['Result'] === 1) {
    this.setState({flag: 1}); 
} else {
    this.setState({flag: 2}); 
}
```

Then this will cause your component to be re-rendered on each state change, and hence your app will become reactive.

Next, if you want to display a warning message to the user when the flag property is equal to 2, simply add a conditional expression in your JSX.

```
{ this.state.flag === 2 && <p>Your login credentials could not be verified, please try again.</p>}
```

What this means is that the `<p>` tag will only be evaluated (hence rendered) if the first part of the expression, i.e. `this.state.flag === 2`, evaluates to true.

If you want to redirect the user to another route upon successful login, simply import the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom` and replace the return statement in your render() method with the following:

```
if (this.state.flag === 1) {
    return <Redirect to='/route' />
}

// else
return (
    <div className = 'outer-container' ref={this.props.containerRef}>
    // ... add the rest of your JSX
)
```

For more info on this solution, please see [this link](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/).

So ultimately, your render() method could look something like the following:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.flag === 1) {
        return <Redirect to='/route' />
    }

    // else
    return (
        <div className = 'outer-container' ref={this.props.containerRef}>
            <div className = 'header'> Login </div>
            <div className="content">
                <div className="image">
                    <img src={LoginImage} />
                </div>
                { this.state.flag === 2 && <p>Your login credentials could not be verified, please try again.</p>}
                // ... add the rest of your JSX
    )
}
```

**~~~ UPDATE ~~~**

If the `<Redirect>` approach does not work, there is another method we can try as well (also detailed [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/)). We can redirect the user programatically after your fetch request resolves, assuming we get the correct flag back from the API. So you can try:

```
if(json['Result'] === 1) {
    this.setState({ flag: 1 }); 
    this.props.history.push('/route')
}
```

In order to use this approach, however, you will also need to wrap your component with the `withRouter` HOF in your export statement. So instead of:

```
export default MyComponent
```

You will need to do:

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Just make sure to import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

If you take this approach, you will no longer need this block of code:

```
if (this.state.flag === 1) {
    return <Redirect to='/route' />
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing it but I am getting an error: 
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>

Comment: I am getting an error in a file which I have not defined:

```TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
new Router
node_modules/react-router/esm/react-router.js:46```

Comment: How did you setup your Router? Please show us your file where you setup your Router and https://codesandbox.io will make troubleshooting much easier.

Comment: There is another approach detailed in the article I linked that you can try as well. I updated my answer to demonstrate how that could be done.